# G as a graph without self loops and parallel edges with n vertices and m edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

EDITED to include c.

Could someone help me understand this problem?  I haven't been able to comprehend what I am supposed to do here.

1) Let G be a graph without self loops and parallel edges with n vertices and m edges.  Consider the following procedure:
  a) $G' \leftarrow G$
  b) While there is a vertex of degree stricly less than $m/n$ do:
c) Remove this vertex and all its edges from the graph, and assign to G` the new graph.
d) Recompute the degrees (note that $M$ and $n$ are fixed)

2) Return $G'$

Honestly, I feel like I should be doing derivatives in Calculus after reading this.  (If that's what I'm actually supposed to do I may break my computer).

Thank you to anyone for your help.

Comment: There's a), b), and d) but no c)? Does the problem ask you to do anything else besides "consider" that procedure? Would "OK, I've considered it" be an acceptable answer?

Comment: What is the problem's question?

Comment: I fixed it to include c, which was actually there but not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

We consider $G := K_{5} \cup P_{3}$. There are $12$ edges and $8$ vertices. So we remove any vertex with degree less than $\dfrac{3}{2}$. So we begin by looking at the vertices of $G$. The endpoints of $P_{3}$ each have degree $1$. And so we remove an endpoint. Now $G^{\prime} = K_{5} \cup P_{2}$. Both endpoints of $P_{2}$ have degree $1$, so we remove an endpoint, and we are left with $G^{\prime} = K_{5} \cup \{v_{6}\}$. As $v_{6}$ has degree $0$, we remove it, and so we are done, leaving $K_{5}$ as the graph.

Note: You mentioned "d) Recompute the degrees (note that M and n are fixed)". And so I did not update the ratio $\dfrac{3}{2}$ on each iteration.

Does this explain the algorithm better?

Comment: A little, but it's still difficult to grasp.  Would drawing a representation of the problem make it easier for me?

Comment: Drawing it and working through the algorithm would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow got lost in this again.  Could you explain your example of K5 union P3? I'm not sure I understand where the vertexes with degrees less than 4/3 are coming from.

Comment: There are 8 vertices and 12 edges. So 12/8 = 3/2. Note that $K_5$ and $P_3$ are disjoint. And there I noticed I made a silly math error. Let me update my post to fix that.